# c# asp net Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ArgumentNullException' en System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un programa creado en c# asp.net, al cambiarme de ordenador y reinstalarlo todo me da un error al ejecutarlo en debug:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ademas imprime esto por consola:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No output has been recevied from the application.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.DebugProxyLauncher.LaunchAndGetUrl(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String devToolsHost)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebAssemblyNetDebugProxyAppBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseWebAssemblyDebugging>b__0_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context, String matchedPath, String remainingPath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[12:48:20 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A59689%2Fdevtools%2Fbrowser%2Fe62011c0-9efe-4df0-80f9-18edcf4afafe - - - 500 - text/plain;+charset=utf-8 65.3127ms
Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ArgumentNullException' en System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Value cannot be null.
```

Y al cabo de un rato sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mejor de todo es que este error es completamente aleatorio y a veces no sale... pero sale al cabo de un rato el mensaje de la tercera imagen igualmente.
He estado buscando toda la mañana y no he encontrado solución en ningún sitio...

Ademas de todo esto el programa antes se ejecutaba automaticamente en una ventana de google en la direccion `https://localhost:50831`

Ahora cuando funciona se carga con `about:blank` y no sale absolutamente nada, tengo que buscar yo la dirección correcta

Por ultimo siento no pasar ninguna imagen de código pero es que como se ve en la primera captura no se está rompiendo en ninguna sentencia en especifico y el contexto donde rompe es demasiado grande como para pasarlo.